# Configurar IP fija en linuxmint 19,3

Tags: redes, ip, networking, linux-mint

Estoy tratando de configurar una ip fija en mi laptop toshiba, pero cuando realizo la configuración y reinicio pierdo las conexiones (no aparece ninguna, ni la por cable ni la wifi)

Los pasos que hago son:

1. Ejecutar ifconfig obtengo estas interfaces **(enp8s0, lo y wlp7s0)**
2. Modifico el archivo */etc/network/interfaces* con lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.Reinicio y ahí es que se pierde todas las conexiones

No se que estoy haciendo mal, ayuda !!!

**Saludos**

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Cómo grabas esos cambios?

Comment: Abro el archivo con: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces luego ctrl+o y ctrl+x